# Constraint layout button text center alignment

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm using the new `Constraint` layout to build my layout. I need to have `Button` that occupies almost the entire screen width and that was easy using constraints.

[image]

As you can see in the image I am setting the width to `0dp` (Any size), but the text don't stick at the center what's usually the normal for a button text.

I've tried:
 - set gravity to center
 - set textAlignment to center

Looks like this properties can't work with `0dp` width (Any size).

So I've tried to set the width to `match_parent` using gravity center.

[image]

It's a little bit to the right.

Does any one know how to fix that behavior ?

Note that i'm using alpha4

`compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'`

XML code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="br.com.marmotex.ui.LoginActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login">

    <Button
        android:text="Log in"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btLogin"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/content_login"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/content_login"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/BackgroundColor" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT** It was a bug in `ConstraintLayout` alpha4.

**UPDATE** Google has released **alpha5**, the above code now Works.
[Release note](http://tools.android.com/recent/constraintlayout-alpha5available)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It's a little bit to the right.

I think margin(s) is causing these. And its not only affecting Buttons, in my experience. Margin is screwing TextInputEditText too.

Below is a working code but please pay attention to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` on the Button. Any time I clicked in the editor, it will change to `android:layout_width="0dp"`, and ruin the button alignment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_survey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_main"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_main"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_main"
        tools:text="@string/main_activity_btn_survey"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Inspired by Hobo joe's solution, below is the way i prefer to did it. His solution is working but still need to use padding to create spacing. If margin was used instead, the alignment of button's text will go slightly to the right. So I used padding on LinearLayout(or ConstraintLayout) instead of margin on button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_main"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_main"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_main"
        android:padding="16dp">
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:id="@+id/button_survey"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:text="@string/main_activity_btn_survey"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Google has released alpha5, update it and you won't need this work around anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried ?

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. However, you can work around it by placing the button inside a LinearLayout (Or other standard ViewGroup). Set the parent view and the button width to `match_parent`, and move whatever constraints you had on the button to the parent layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/parent_left"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/parent_top"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/parent_right">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Centered Text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout code? I just tested with the XML I posted and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think its because of these constraints 
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf

replace your current button with this one :

```
    <Button
    android:text="Log in"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:id="@+id/btLogin"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@color/BackgroundColor"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-1dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is with `android:layout_width="match_parent"` when using inside `ConstraintLayout`.
Just set `android:layout_width="0dp"` and add constraints `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` & `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`, it'd just work fine.

```
<Button
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Continue"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```