# How to bring all the content of the layout at centre in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am making a login screen where I have 2 `EditText` and 2 `Buttons`.  I have placed them in vertical way one below each other. But I want to bring all the content at centre in my layout.

Below is my `activity_login.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/loginLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/emailLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_action_user"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextLabel" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/passwordLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/logi">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_action_password"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextLabel" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginSubmit"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordLayout" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerText"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:theme="@style/RegistrationButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginSubmit" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the image of the layout:
[image]

**I am not able to bring those views at the centre.**

Comment: Actually they seem to be "centered". But I guess you want them to be of smaller width centered? Or do you mean vertically centered?

Comment: vertically centered @MichaelTroger

Comment: put all view in one parent layout and set gravity of parent layout to center.

Comment: But in ConstraintLayout we should avoid adding depth to views right ? @niveshshastri

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center the elements in ConstraintLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143468/how-to-center-the-elements-in-constraintlayout)

Comment: **I think u should follow below link:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747040/constraint-layout-button-text-center-alignment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using packed chaining in my `ConstraintLayout`. So, yours should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/loginLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/emailLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/passwordLayout"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_action_user"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextLabel" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/passwordLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/loginSubmit"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_action_password"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextLabel" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginSubmit"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/registerText"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerText"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:theme="@style/RegistrationButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginSubmit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The resultant layout should be as follows:

[image: Packed chaining at work in ConstraintLayout]

Answer (score 8):

First make sure you use an up to date version of the *ConstraintLayout* (at the time of writing 1.0.2). You can achieve vertical centering by giving the top most element (*emailLayout*) the `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"` attribute.

Besides that you need to make sure that all elements are connected like a chain in the code. I.e. the upper most view (*emailLayout*) is under constraint of the parent on top and under constraint of the next sibling (*passwordLayout*) on the bottom.

The second view (*passwordLayout*) needs to be under constraint of the sibling before it at the top (*emailLayout*) and under constraint of the next sibling (*loginSubmit*) at the bottom and so on...

The last view (*registerText*) has a top constraint to the sibling before as well but has a bottom constraint to the bottom of the parent.

Hint: `android:orientation="vertical"` is useless in a *ConstraintLayout*. You can leave this out.

EDIT:
Here a minimum code example of vertical centering with the *ConstraintLayout*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view2"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view3"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Resulting in:

[image]